# A special diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could someone please tell me if the following variation of diagonally dominant matrix is a well studied thing and is there any name for it. I'll call it special diagonally dominant matrix.

*def: A square matrix is called a special diagonally dominant matrix if in each row, the diagonal entry is greater than or equal to **every other** entry of that row.*

Note: the usual definition of diagonally dominant matrix is that the diagonal entry should be more than or equal to **Sum** of the other entries of that row.

Comment: I don't know of a name for this property, but it implies that every $2\times 2$ principal submatrix is positive semidefinite, which is a property called "2-locally PSD" (see https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.04031 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05110 for example).